# How to set Content-Type to exactly "text/plain" on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-headers, content-type

The code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("hello", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

is responding with header

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

My question is how to remove "; charset=utf-8" from response header Content-Type?

Here [How do I remove the charset from Content-Type in a ASP.NET Core MVC response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708527) it is how to do it on asp.net core.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @Moo-Juice, client wants so

Comment: @thirdDeveloper, no, it is not duplicate, there about core

Comment: Removing it will have no effect, and clients will just assume `charset=utf8` anyway. Pointless.

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the `Charset` before `Content()`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.Charset = "";
    return Content("hello", "text/plain");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this one.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
     return Content("your content");
}
```

Comment: how can you say not helpted ?

Comment: I mean it doesn't work for me - on response header there present charset part